# prove that u(f(t), t) is constant in t

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

"Suppose that u(x,t) satisfies the differential equation u<sub>t</sub> + uu<sub>x</sub> =0 and that x, as a function x=f(t) of t, satisfies dx/dt=u(x,t). Prove that u(f(t),t) is constant in t."

I am not sure where to start with this. The books suggests letting x=f(t) and y=t and then using the chain rule to differentiate u(x,y) with respect to t, but when I tried that I didn't get anywhere. Help or hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}u-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$, where in the second equality, I've used $u=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Comment: How did you get to that? I'm still kind of confused, sorry..

Comment: The first equality is just the chain rule for $\frac{du}{dt}$. In the second equality, I made the substitutions $u=\frac{dx}{dt}$ (you gave that as part of the problem) and $u_t=-uu_x$, because $u$ satisfies that differential equation (also given as part of the problem). Let me know if you're still confused

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you so much!